# What type of In-App Purchase I need to use for my iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewable

I'm developing an iOS app where users can subscribe to celebrity contents (**like their photos and videos**).

App has two types of user accounts.

*1) Regular User.*

*2)Celebrity.*

- Regular users can subscribe to any celebrity content they want. So I guess it has to be only one subscription group with one `IAP` i.e '**Monthly Celeb Content**'. So that makes only one type of `IAP`(**auto renewable subscription**) for all celebrities to be subscribed one by one. Subscription is auto renewable every month.

But how do I make sure which celebrity content user has subscribed? Do I need to create same number of `IAPs` as number of celebrity accounts?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use auto-renewing subscriptions you will need a different IAP product for each celebrity.

Comment: so if I have 300 celebrity accounts, I will have to create 300 different IAP products for same group with same settings. Right? First time I'm working on IAP.  Need to figure out which IAP product id belongs to which celebrity. Thanks for clearing my confusion though.

Comment: No, you would want 300 different IAP products in 300 different groups.  User can upgrade/downgrade within a group (so they might upgrade from a monthly subscription to an annual subscription).  Personally, I don't think your app is a particularly good match for IAP subscriptions; if you need to add a new celebrity, you will need to release a new version of your app as new IAPs must be released with a new version of your app

Comment: so is there other way around to solve this? This is client's requirement so I have to figure out the best solution for this challenge. What would you recommend?

Comment: What about creating 4 different subscription of monthly, quarterly, half annually and annually. And a user with subscription can subscribe to any number of celebrities. Is there any problem with this implementation?